# JQuery Default case delay fadeout, when mouseenter stay visible, after mouseout fadeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-events

I'm trying to make it so a box will automatically fade out after 3 seconds if nothing is done, but if the user puts their mouse in the box it will stop/prevent the fade out and will continue to show, then once the user's mouse leaves it will fade out.

I tried it with HTML:

```
<div id="box">box</div>
```

and JQuery:

```
$("#box").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");

$("#box").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#box").stop().fadeIn("fast");
});
$("#box").mouseout(function(){
    $("#box").delay(1000).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

What happens is that the initial delay will still fade out if the mouse is over it and once the fadeout is complete it will do the fade in.

Comment: `initial delay will still fade out` => it will! because there is no condition on it be stopped.

Comment: I thought .stop() would clear the animations currently in progress. I just found out that I have to use .stop(true,true) which it looks like it's supposed to clear the queue and then jump to the end of the animation queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess default `.stop()` has clear queue and jumptoend as false so it will finish all animations first. I had to use

```
.stop(true, true)
```

In order to clear the queue and end all the animations currently in progress.
I just realized they were both set to false in the JQuery documentation.

**.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )**

**clearQueue (default: false)**
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.

**jumpToEnd (default: false)**
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.